# How do I check the value inside a text feild while using ruby selenium testing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium

I am running a selenium test using ruby and was wondering how I can assert the value inside a text field?

I have a page where once it's loaded has text inside the editable text field and I was wondering how I can check if the text is present?

Comment: Sentences begin with a capital letter, and "i" is capitalized, and "field" is spelt with i before e.

Comment: thank you for your comment but i didn't know this was a grammar correction site

Comment: @Mo: That's fine. I won't try to correct the grammar of any other stuff you write.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
assert_equal "myValue", @selenium.get_value("id=myField")
```